# PHP Spread Sheet pre filtered columns

Tags: php, xml, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I am adding an auto filter to my spread sheet successfully but what I would like to do is apply a filter to the sheet before saving. For example I have a `RetailerID` column with three possible values `(13, 42, 326)`. How do I save the sheet already filtered by `RetailerID = 42`?

I have found in the XML the difference:

```xml
<autoFilter ref="A1:O1290" xr:uid="{00000000-0009-0000-0000-000000000000}">
    <filterColumn colId="0">
        <filters>
            <filter val="42"/>
        </filters>
    </filterColumn>
</autoFilter>
```

But changing this by hand does not hide the rows as each row that needs hidden needs the `'hidden="1"'` attribute. How can I accomplish this in PHP Spread Sheets?

EDIT:
Current Code looks like this

```
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->fromArray(array_keys($laundry_pairs[0]), null, 'A1');
    // Set title row bold
    $sheet->getStyle('A1:E1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    //set title row color
    $sheet->getStyle('A1:O1')->getFill()
        ->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
        ->getStartColor()->setARGB('71eb0e');

    //add rows of data
    $row_num = 2;
    foreach($laundry_pairs as $row_data){
        $sheet->fromArray($row_data, null, 'A' . (string)$row_num++);
    }
    
    //set the column widths to display all textdomain
    for ($col=chr(65); $col < chr(80); $col++){
        $sheet->getColumnDimension((string)$col)->setAutoSize(true);
    }
    
    //set auto filters
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->calculateWorksheetDimension());
    // Save
    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save('laundry_pairs.xlsx');
```

please ignore the weird way I am iterating over cells. I do know now you can access by row, col index.

Comment: you might wanna show us the PHP code you are using to save the data. that way we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what I was looking for in the samples on the github page.
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/samples/Autofilter/10_Autofilter_selection_display.php

```
$autoFilter = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getAutoFilter();
$autoFilter->getColumn('C')
    ->setFilterType(Column::AUTOFILTER_FILTERTYPE_CUSTOMFILTER)
    ->createRule()
    ->setRule(
        Rule::AUTOFILTER_COLUMN_RULE_EQUAL,
        42
    );
```